# Another Codeigniter Property Undefined issue

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I'm getting this, but I don't understand why.:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Menu::$menu_model
Filename: controllers/menu.php
Line Number: 16


Fatal error: Call to a member function get_menu() on a non-object in /home/.../modules/menu/controllers/menu.php on line 16
```

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9923160/codeigniter-model-undefined-property), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5547912/codeigniter-undefined-property-error-on-model) and [the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440226/codeigniter-undefined-property-when-loading-a-model). But even with my simple code, it still breaks.

The Controller

```
class Menu extends CI_Controller
{
    /**
     * Constructor method
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function index($layout = -1)
    {
        $this->load->model('menu_model');
        // There is no $this->menu_model at this point. If I echo it out, it says property undefined as well.
        $data['menu'] = $this->menu_model->get_menu($layout);  // It fails on this line.
        $data['thisurl'] = $this->uri->uri_string();
        $this->load->view('menu.php');
    }

}
```

The Model

```
class Menu_model extends CI_Model 
{
    public function get_menu($layout = -1)
    {
        $menu = array(
            0 => array('href' => '/', 'label' => 'Home', FALSE),
            1 => array('href' => '/about', 'label' => 'About', FALSE),
            2 => array('href' => '/help', 'label' => 'Help', FALSE)
        );

        return $menu;
    }
}
```

The file is loaded successfully. If I change the class name to Menu_model_fail... I get an error, and if I change the load->model('menu_model_break') I also get an error. So I know it's loading the file correctly.

Comment: It looks like you are using the MX modular extension - what happens if you change your controller to extend from MX_Controller instead of CI_Controller?

Comment: subtle side note - what's the point of passing $layout if you don't use it?

Comment: I will, not there yet. I got stuck on the model not loading.

Comment: @Darrrrrren if you post that as an answer, I'll accept. That was it.

Comment: Thanks @Foobar, I've added it as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are using the MX modular extension - you should change your controller to extend from MX_Controller instead of CI_Controller.

Comment: say, out of curiosity what indicated this was using the MX modular extension?

Comment: @KaiQing `/modules/` was referenced in the error path output.

Comment: aah good catch. I've worked on tons of CI projects but not many that used modules. I didn't even see that.

Comment: Cheers :-) I pretty much only use CI with the modular extension - makes it so much easier to organize larger apps.